# Search box displays all comments made by one user when only two were made by that user

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I search the first name of a user who made a reply I get that user, but when I search the first name of a user who made a comment the search page makes it looks as if a user typed in all of the comments, it works fine for replies, but not for comments.

HTML code for Search Box:

```
  <div class="form">
    <form action="search_page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="dark" name="search"/>
     <button><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>
</div>
```

PHP code for Search Box:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th>First_Name</th>
 <th>Date</th>
 <th>Reply</th>
</tr>
<?php 
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","CENSORED","CENSORED","configurenow");
  $set = $_POST['search'];
if($set) {
   $show = "SELECT * FROM replies where first_name='$set'";
   $result = mysqli_query($db,$show);
   while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo  "<tr>";
     echo  "<td>";
     echo $rows['first_name'];
     echo  "</td>";
     echo  "<td>";
     echo $rows['date'];
     echo  "</td>";
     echo  "<td>";
     echo $rows['reply'];
     echo "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
   }
 }
else {
  echo "Nothing Found";
}

if($set) {
   $show = "SELECT * FROM comments,users where first_name='$set'";
   $result = mysqli_query($db,$show);
   while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo  "<tr>";
     echo  "<td>";
     echo $rows['first_name'];
     echo  "</td>";
     echo  "<td>";
     echo $rows['date'];
     echo  "</td>";
     echo  "<td>";
     echo $rows['message'];
     echo "</td>";
     echo  "</tr>";
   }
 }
else {
  echo "Nothing Found";
}
?>
</table>
```

SQL:

```
first_name - varchar(200) utf8_unicode_ci
date - datetime 
message - text
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Because maybe you care about your data

Comment: I understand that but right now we want to fix the problem before we went any further so we can safely protect that information too before moving any further. But if we did practice SQL injection that would cause more issues than the one at hand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does not work because you are not joining the SQL tables, just comma-separating them.

Comment: If you’re going to build a house, get the foundation right before you frame it. It’s a lot harder to replace the foundation after you build the house.  As to your question, you’re making a Cartesian join in the second query. You’ve joined every row in comments to every row in users. You should be joining comments using foreign key user id.

Comment: When you refer to user id, do you mean uid? Because when I use uid, all I get is the user's number. What would be the correct method to join 2 tables? If by using JOIN you mean using this method? ``` SELECT * FROM comments JOIN users where first_name='$set' ``` because I've tried that and all the comments are still appearing as if they are made by 1 user.

Comment: To help avoid Cartesian joins, I would use ansi style query: define the join in the from clause instead of the where clause. As an example, `select * from comments inner join users on comments.userid=users.id where first_name=?`

Comment: We don't have a column named userid though, so would we change comments.userid to -> comments.uid, like this? ``` select * from comments inner join users on comments.uid=users.id where first_name=? ``` Thank you

Comment: You must have a field that relates the tables together. I assumed userid, since the user id is what would logically be the relation.  When I have time and access to a computer (on my phone), I’ll give an answer within a day

Comment: Ah, so you mean like a column that both tables have? If not then, thank you for you answer, I shall wait, thank you for helping!

Comment: We are aware that our SQL is vulnerable, and we plan to correct that later on, but we have decided for now to focus on the task at hand. Thank you for being concerned though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second query, `SELECT * FROM comments,users where first_name='$set'` is the one that needs the most work (although both are insecure).   As written, it means to join every row of comments with every row of users and then keep the rows that have `first_name=$set`.   Since all possible combinations of rows have been made, your result set will be every row in comments, duplicated by the number of times the where condition was met in users.

Clearly, this is not what you wanted.

So the question is, what should the query look like?  To answer this, you need to go back to how relational databases work. The key word (pun intended) is relational. You must have at least one field that relates the two tables together.  For more information on this concept, google “database normalization”.

In this case, you probably want a one-to-many relationship between comments and users; I.e., a comment belongs to one user, and a user has many comments.

```
Comments     Users
id          
user_id ———> id 
comment      first_name
```

So imagine joe, user id 1, makes a comment. You would insert a record into comments with user_id 1 and the comment. Joe then makes a second comment. Then Sally makes a comment.  The tables would hold:

```
Users
id   first_name
1    Joe
2    Sally 


Comments
id    user_id    comment 
1     1          Comment one
2     1          Comment two
3     2          Sally’s comment one
```

Now that there is a relationship between the tables, you can generate a query that gathers all comments that belong to a certain user.   I recommend using a different syntax from the one that uses a comma between tables in the from clause and makes the relation in the where clause.

```
select * 
from comments 
inner join users on comments.user_id = users.id
```

This ties the tables together, now filter by your criteria:

```
select * 
from comments 
inner join users on comments.user_id = users.id
where first_name = ?
```

The question mark is a placeholder for a prepared query. To make it easier to learn how to use prepared statements, I would suggest using PDO instead of mysqli. (Mysqli certainly will work, but it is in my opinion confusing campared to PDO.)

The query still needs some tightening up.  As it is right now, it has some ambiguities.  These could cause some problems. Two things need to change:  the select should be explicit in which fields it wants, and the where clause also needs to be precise.  To do so, we'll use aliasing.

```
select c.id, c.comment, u.first_name
from comments c
inner join users u on c.user_id = u.id
where u.first_name = ?
```

If data integrity (and/or performance) is important, look into setting up comments.user_id as a [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).  This will ensure, for example, that a comment cannot be created if the user does not exist.  It can also prevent deleting a user unless all the user's comments are deleted first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have found a different source to fix it, thank you for your help!